# Why API call take 80 ms latency to reach controller (in Google App Engine)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

[image]

For every Api call to reach controller, it is taking 80ms latency, i have tried all the instance classes, result is same, i have not found any solution for this. As show in the image, RPC call starts at 80th ms, remaining time spending out side of my code.

Comment: We have no idea either. We cannot see your network configuration.  This question is extremely far off-topic for StackOverflow as it has to do with the network between you and Google, and not anything to do with software development.  You might try [sf] but unless you provide lots of supporting data, including traceroutes, expect it to be off-topic there as well.

Comment: Is your app getting regular traffic?

Comment: @JimGarrison There might be a legitimate issue question here posed exactly as phrased. App Engine isn't a typical web server, but rather a platform as a service offering that scales to zero with additional latency for when the first instances comes up.

Comment: yeah, 0.5 requests/sec

Answer (score 2):

Well, there may be **a lot** of GAE infra code executing for every request **before** your app code is invoked - it's the nature of PaaS: it gives you the convenience of simpler app code by taking a portion of the stuff that needs to be executed and performing it for you.

Similarly there will be time spent in the framework(s) and libraries you use to simplify your app code. Even if it's not literally your code it's still your app's code.

You can get a glimpse (not necessarily quantitative) of that by checking some real full strack traces seen on GAE. At least in my (python) app's case a stack trace often shows several times more calls outside my code than calls from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your [App Engine logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) for the request that initiated this trace. Do you see a message stating:

> "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."

If so, the latency is likely due to low demand on your app and with increased demand the latency would be infrequent.

Otherwise, you should probably post your code that is being executed to dive into what could be taking longer.

Comment: Hi @BrettJ, Thanks for your answer, I have not found any messages like that in the logs, i have added warmup request, and this is happening for every api call, i have kept the log in handle method of the Restlet(as per the logs timings, it took 60 to 80 ms to reach there)

Comment: Hey Brett, it would be awesome if warmup requests would take 80ms. In my years using app engine I have not seen a warmup request for a Java application that only takes 80ms. So I'm pretty sure that this is not the case here.

Comment: Perhaps look into appstats and see if that can reveal more for you: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats