# How do I stop this Google cloude Instances billing?

Tags: google-app-engine

I do some FireBase tutorials and now I see in my billings I have the:

> Dec 1 – 21, 2016 App Engine Backend Instances: 239.56 Hours
>   (Source:joga Port Project [joga-port-project]) $9.73

How do I stop this billing without delete the hole project?
The backend is just one `Servlet` for testing sending emails but I dont want to delete my hard work.

I go to Instances page at Settings and stop the Instance from running.
Will this be enough so it wont cost money and can I just start it whenever I want to use it?

[image]

Comment: what scaling type and what instance  class are you using?

Comment: I have this in the  appengine-web.xml -    `<manual-scaling>
        <instances>1</instances>
    </manual-scaling>` I dont know what an  instance class is

Comment: see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/an-overview-of-app-engine#scaling_types_and_instance_classes

Answer (score 0):

Turning the instances off won't help if you use dynamic scaling - GAE will start them up again when a new request comes in.

It will work, but only if you use manual scaling. But your site won't, obviously, be working when the instances are off.  See [Scaling elements](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#scaling_elements)

You *might* be able to keep the site working yet still remain within the free daily quotas by using a cheap instance type and basic scaling with a **max_instances** config.  See 
[Python App Engine webapp2 slow to route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990594/python-app-engine-webapp2-slow-to-route/40997415#40997415)

Comment: Thanks, I do some FireBase tutorials no production stuff

Comment: thanks, I have this ` appengine-web.xml - <manual-scaling> <instances>1</instances> </manual-scaling> ` so you think it will work