# Concurrent requests in The App Engine Standard Environment

Tags: python, django, multithreading, google-app-engine, concurrency

I'm using Django 1.10.5 on The App Engine Standard Environment python27 runtime.

My `app.yaml` looks like:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: F4_1G
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: 1
  max_idle_instances: automatic # default value
  max_concurrent_requests: 8 # default value
  max_pending_latency: 30ms # default value

- url: /.*
  script: myapp.wsgi.application
  secure: always
```

So I use wsgi, which supports threads, and threadsafe is true.

I'm doing simple stress test with https://github.com/rakyll/hey on simple hello-world page and get following results:

**2 concurrent requests**

`hey -more -c 2 -n 100 -m GET https://<test-app-url>.appspot.com`

```
Response time histogram:
  0.074 [1] |∎
  0.214 [62]|∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  0.354 [20]|∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  0.495 [6] |∎∎∎∎
  0.635 [6] |∎∎∎∎
  0.775 [4] |∎∎∎
  0.916 [0] |
  1.056 [0] |
  1.197 [0] |
  1.337 [0] |
  1.477 [1] |∎
```

**8 concurrent requests**

`hey -more -c 8 -n 100 -m GET https://<test-app.appspot>.appspot.com`

```
Response time histogram:
  0.083 [1] |∎
  0.590 [74]|∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎∎
  1.098 [11]|∎∎∎∎∎∎
  1.605 [6] |∎∎∎
  2.112 [0] |
  2.619 [2] |∎
  3.127 [1] |∎
  3.634 [0] |
  4.141 [0] |
  4.649 [0] |
  5.156 [1] |∎
```

How can I control/monitor/debug threads behaviour?
The only setting I know is `max_concurrent_requests: 8` (only available while using automatic_scaling), does this mean max 8 threads per instance?
How can I control threads per instance in basic/manual scaling? How to explain latency increase with more concurrent requests?

Comment: Check your app's logs - do you see info logs for some of the requests stating that new instances are started for them and they will take longer?

Comment: Yep, I see one request caused a new process to be started for application

Comment: In traces, some of requests start immediately, some of requests wait for smth. http://imgur.com/a/CXknx

Comment: Ah, those may be difficult to answer. See similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40903777/why-api-call-take-80-ms-latency-to-reach-controller-in-google-app-engine and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990594/python-app-engine-webapp2-slow-to-route

Comment: I thought you're targeting those outlayers with very long latencies, not the slightly longer than average ones :) I was thinking that the outlayers could be instance-starting requests and that's marked in the app's request logs.

Comment: Any ideas about control/monitor/debug threads ?

Comment: Nope, I don't remember seeing anything on this.

Comment: FYI, RE: "How can I control threads per instance in basic/manual scaling?" - I seem to recall that for basic/manual scaling you get 8 concurrent requests/instance if you have "threadsafe: true".